# Graph a series of planes as a solid object in Mathematica

Tags: optimization, graphics, wolfram-mathematica, fill

I'm trying to graph a series of planes as a solid object in mathematica. I first tried to use the RangePlot3D options as well as the fill options to graph the 3D volume, but was unable to find a working result.

The graphic I'm trying to create will show the deviation between the z axis and the radius from the origin of a 3D cuboid. The current equation I'm using is this:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[{Sqrt[(C[1])^2 + x^2 + y^2]} /. 
C[1] -> Range[6378100, 6379120]], {x, -1000000, 
1000000}, {y, -1000000, 1000000}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

(output for more manageable range looks as follows)

Where C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtG4Z.jpg) was the origional Z-value at each plane and the result of this equation is z+(r-z)
for any point on the x,y plane.

However this method is incredibly inefficient. Because this will be used to model large objects with an original z-values of >6,000,000 and heights above 1000, mathematica is unable to graph thousands of planes and represent them in a responsive method.

Additionally, Because the Range of C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtG4Z.jpg) only includes integer values, there is discontinuity between these planes.

Is there a way to rewrite this using different mathematica functionality that will generate a 3Dplot that is both a reasonable load on my system and is a smooth object?

2nd, What can I do to improve my perforamance? when computing the above input for >30min, mathematica was only utilizing about 30% CPU and 4GB of ram with a light load on my graphics card as well. This is only about twice as much as chrome is using right now on my system.

I attempted to enable CUDALink, but it wouldn't enable properly. Would this offer a performance boost for this type of processing?

For Reference, my system build is:
16GB Ram
Intel i7 4770K running at stock settings
Nvidia GeForce 760GTX
256 Samsung SSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting a million planes and hoping that becomes a 3d solid seems unlikely to succeed.

Perhaps you could adapt something like this

```
Show[Plot3D[{Sqrt[6^2+x^2+y^2], Sqrt[20^2+x^2+y^2]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, All}], 
  Graphics3D[{
   Polygon[Join[
    Table[{x, -10, Sqrt[6^2 + x^2 + (-10)^2]}, {x, -10, 10, 1}], 
    Table[{x, -10, Sqrt[20^2 + x^2 + (-10)^2]}, {x, 10, -10, -1}]]], 
   Polygon[Join[
    Table[{-10, y, Sqrt[6^2 + (-10)^2 + y^2]}, {y, -10, 10, 1}], 
    Table[{-10, y, Sqrt[20^2 + (-10)^2 + y^2]}, {y, 10, -10, -1}]]], 
   Polygon[Join[
    Table[{x, 10, Sqrt[6^2 + x^2 + 10^2]}, {x, -10, 10, 1}], 
    Table[{x, 10, Sqrt[20^2 + x^2 + 10^2]}, {x, 10, -10, -1}]]], 
   Polygon[Join[
    Table[{10, y, Sqrt[6^2 + 10^2 + y^2]}, {y, -10, 10, 1}], 
    Table[{10, y, Sqrt[20^2 + 10^2 + y^2]}, {y, 10, -10, -1}]]]}]]
```

[image]

What that does is plot the top and bottom surface and then construct four polygons, each connecting the top and bottom surface along one side. But one caution, if you look very very closely you will see that, because they are polygons, the edges of the four faces are made up of short line segments rather than parabolas and thus are not perfectly joining your two paraboloids, there can be tiny gaps or tiny overlaps. This may or may not make any difference for your application.

That graphic displays in a fraction of a second on a machine that is a fraction of yours.

Mathematica does not automatically parallelize computations onto multiple cores.
CUDA programming is a considerably bigger challenge than turning the link on.
If you can simply define each face of your solid and combine them with Show then
I think you will have a much greater chance of success.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
 xyrange = 10
 cmin  = 6
 cmax = 20
 RegionPlot3D[
    Abs[x] < xyrange && Abs[y] < xyrange && 
     cmin^2  <  z^2 - ( x^2 + y^2) < cmax^2  ,
     {x, -1.2 xyrange,  1.2 xyrange}, {y, -1.2 xyrange, 1.2 xyrange},
     {z, cmin,  Sqrt[ cmax^2 + 2 xyrange^2]}, MaxRecursion -> 15, 
             PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

This is nowhere near as fast as Bills' approach, but it may be useful if you plot a more complicated region.  Note `RegionPlot` does not work for your original example because the volume is too small compared to the plot range.